# A hero regular expression challenge

Tags: grep

I've spent the whole afternoon trying to figure this out and I think you guys probably know the answer in 5 minutes.

I need to list  occurrences of a string in a file like this.

look for (0 to many) of (a-z, A-Z, 0-9, _, -) followed by CHRIS or DAVE followed by (0 to many) of (a-z, A-Z, 0-9, _, -)

so for a file like this:

```
eader>fooCHRISbar</header>
madeup>DAVE123 more stuff after space
more stuff hereCHRISDAVE</done>
blah CHRIS.internet.com</done>
```

would return

```
fooCHRISbar
DAVE123
hereCHRISDAVE
CHRIS.internet.com
```

..basically it's looking for all occurences of CHRIS and DAVE including the surrounding text (a character, underscore or dash all the way up to a < or space or something

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `.` in the second character class condition. So that it would match the string `CHRIS.INTERNET.COM`,

```
$ grep -oP '[\w-]*(?:CHRIS|DAVE)[\w.-]*' file
fooCHRISbar
DAVE123
hereCHRISDAVE
CHRIS.internet.com
```

Comment: if the dot occurs before `CHRIS` then you need to add `.` inside first char class. `grep -oP '[\w.-]*(?:CHRIS|DAVE)[\w.-]*' file`